# Create new Gradle based Android project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, intellij-eap

The title pretty much says it all. I would like to create a new Gradle based Android project in IntelliJ IDEA (13 EAP) like I can do in Android Studio.

I've tried creating a new Android Project in IntelliJ but it uses the "old" build system, while creating a new Gradle Project creates a generic java project which doesn't have Android integration at all.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6):

1. Create an android project
2. Create an empty file `build.gradle' in the root of your project
3. Add to the file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

4. Menu `Run` > `Edit configurations` and add(`+`) Groovy run/debug configuration
5. Fill script path to the previously created file 'build.gradle'
6. Fill `Script parameters` with desirable task( e.g. `installDebug` or `assemble`)

To add `adb` shell command you may add new task to this script. Sample:

```
task launchDefaultActivity(type:Exec){
    commandLine './adb', 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-c', 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER', '-n', 'com.example.AndroidGradle/.LaunchActivity'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an update: for IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.0, you can follow this [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-a-gradle-android-project.html)

As suggested, I just quote the details here

To create a Gradle-based Android project, do one of the following:

> 1. If you are going to create a new project: click Create New Project on the Welcome screen or select File | New Project. As a result, the
>      New Project wizard opens. If you are going to add a module to an
>      existing project: open the project you want to add a module to, and
>      select File | New Module. As a result, the New Module wizard opens.
> 2. On the first page of the wizard, in the left-hand pane, select Android. In the right-hand part of the page, select Gradle: Android
>      Module. Click Next.
> 3. Specify the JDK and Android SDK to be used, and click Next.
> 4. Specify your Android module settings, and click Next.
> 5. Specify the settings for your Android-Gradle Foreground configuration, and click Next.
> 6. Select an Android application template from the list, and click Next.
> 7. Specify the settings for the selected Android Activity template, and click Next.
> 8. Specify the name and location settings. For more information, see Project Name and Location or Module Name and Location.
> 9. Click Finish.

Comment: Altough this answer ist quiet old, let me add some infos:
the new version 14.1.x do not offer a gradle-android-modul as a choice.